# How to close cmd after opening a file using Python in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a written a program using Python to open a particular file (txt) which it creates during execution. I have made a batch file to access the script using command line. The batch script is as follows:

```
@echo off
python F:\program\script.py %*
```

I have tried these two options for opening the file with Python in script.py.

```
subprocess.Popen(name, shell=True)
```

and

```
os.system('"'+name+'"')
```

I have further made a keyboard shortcut for the batch script. The problem is I want the cmd prompt to close after the text file opens in notepad. But I have to either manually close the cmd prompt or close the notepad file which automatically closes the cmd prompt.

So my question is how can I close the cmd prompt and keep the notepad file open?

Comment: You don't need a batch file to run a script. Name it "script.pyw". The .pyw extension should be associated with either pyw.exe or pythonw.exe, neither of which open a console window. To open a text file in the script, use `os.startfile(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

To execute a child program in a new process use `Popen`

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen( [ "notepad.exe", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" ] )
```